# Error using categorical Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. Class 'categorical' defines abstract methods and/or properties

Tags: matlab

Why am I getting this error in matlab when running this command:

```
sp = categorical(species);
```

I have loaded two vectors of which one is:

```
species <150 x 1 cell>
```

Comment: [This could help to get answers on your question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using MATLAB-2013a so, the command:

```
 sp = categorical(species);
```

As we know `species` is loaded as a column vector and it needs to be converted to a matrix of double (positive values). We have to run following commands in order to make this vector compatible to the functions input-argument:

```
sp = nominal(species);
sp = double(sp);
```

These above two lines do the same work in MATLAB-2013a (as much as I know) in replacement for

```
sp=categorical(species);
```